# Wrong lon and lat

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have shapefile with wrong coordinates, it's had replaced x coordinate with y coordinate. For example my point feature have coordinates:

`4830698,7496859`

and correct coordinates are:

`7496859, 4830698`

How I can replace these coordinates in all features from shapefile?

I am using QGIS 2.2.0!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using QGIS, you can use the SwapXY plugin.

You can also do this with GDAL/OGR: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQVector#HowdoIflipcoordinateswhentheyarenotintheexpectedorder